# How can I use a .oft SVG font in WPF

Tags: wpf, svg, fonts

I'm making an app with WPF and I need my client to be able to use .oft SVG fonts like the one at https://www.typewithpride.com.

The problem comes when using them. If I send any type of font other than SVG as a function parameter it works fine, however, when using SVG fonts the original colors are not preserved.

How can I fix this?

This is the code I am currently using:

```
// Carga la fuente desde el archivo
           PrivateFontCollection fontCollection = new PrivateFontCollection();
           fontCollection.AddFontFile(fontFilePath);

           // Crea una fuente WPF basada en la fuente cargada
           System.Drawing.FontFamily fontFamily = fontCollection.Families[0];
           System.Windows.Media.FontFamily wpfFontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(fontFamily.Name);

           TextBlock textObject = new TextBlock
           {
               Text = text,
               FontFamily = wpfFontFamily,
               FontSize = size,
               FontWeight = bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal,
               FontStyle = italic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal,
               Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(textColor),
               Opacity = transparency,
               Name = objectID,
           };
```

Comment: SVG isn't supported, let alone oft fonts. You would need to treat each letter as something like a drawing and work with geometries.

Comment: Any idea in how can I do that?

Comment: Each of the different coloured shapes will be defined by a geometry inside that svg font. Two colours in a letter means two geometries. Start by obtaining or extracting them.

Comment: Rather than using WPF, if you migrated to Windows XAML then you could use DirectWrite and Direct2D, which can support OpenType fonts with SVG colour glyphs, like the font you mentioned. If you need to stick with WPF, then you could look for a way to host a Direct2D render target within a WPF control, or to create a D2D bitmap render target and use that as a source for a WPF control.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113991/Using-Direct2D-with-WPF